# Why Are Calculate and Clear Buttons on Top of Each Other?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, button

[image]

The two buttons, Calculate and Clear, are on top of each other instead of next to each other. This is for a basic calculator application (the solution appears in the light green textbox after the user hits "Calculate"). The Calculate and Clear buttons are both inside of a div tag. Here is the full html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Calculator</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<script src="calculator.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<section>
<h1>Calculator</h1>

<label> </label>
<input class="noLabel" type="text" id="sum" disabled="disabled">
<br>
<label>First Number:</label>
<input type="text" id="firstNumber">    
<br>
<label>Second Number:</label>
<input type="text" id="secondNumber">
<br>

<div>
<input type="button" id="calc" value="Calculate">
<input type="button" id="clear" value="Clear">
</div>

</section>
</body>

</html>
```

If I put them in two separate div tags, they will be on two separate rows instead of side by side. Not sure what I've done wrong. Thanks in advance for your help. Here is my CSS:

```
input {
    margin-left: -5em;
    margin-bottom: .5em;
}

label {
    width: 11em;
    float:left;
}

h1 {
    color:black;
    text-align:center;
}

section {
    padding: 0 2em 1em;
    border: grey solid; 
    background-color: #DCDCDC;
    width: 350px;
}

    div {
    margin-left: 11em;
}

input.noLabel {
    margin-left:11em;
    background-color: Beige;
    color: blue;
}
```

[image]

[image]

And then div {margin-left:8em;} to div {margin-left:7.5em;} in CSS:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the Cause

```
input 
{
    margin-left: -5em;
    margin-bottom: .5em;
}
```

Change it to

```
input:not([type='button']) 
{
    margin-left: -5em;
    margin-bottom: .5em;
}
```

Comment: It worked! (See new image at bottom of post). I just had to change the margin-left: em for the div in my CSS to position them properly. Thank you!